# Using Eclipse AST for Parameter Usage

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm looking for a way to locate which MethodInvocation expressions utilize the parameters declared by the caller method.

For example:

```
 public void caller(int param1, int param2){
     m1(param1)
     m2(param2)
     m3(param1, m4(param2))

 }
```

I want to be able to identify that the m1 method invocation utilized 'param1', and that the m2 method invocation utilized 'param2', and that m3 utilized 'param1' and 'param2'. Can I do this with an ASTVisitor? I've had no luck because MethodDeclaration.parameters() provides a list of SingleVariableDeclaration while MethodInvocation.arguments() provides a list of Expression. I do not see a link between SingleVariableDeclaration and Expression. I could just analyze them by their names, but that would be far too naive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings are the definitive way to identify a variable, field, method, class etc. Here, you need to compare the IVariableBinding of the parameter declaration and the reference.

Comment: How can I be sure that an argument held by a method invocation is in fact a variable? For the case provided above, the m3 method invocation contains one expression that has just a variable, but another that has a another method invocation.

Comment: Are you aware of the ASTView plugin - http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php? You should be able to figure out using this plugin how to identify if an expression is a variable or not.

Comment: Yes, I've been working with that. I didn't see a direct connection, but I guess I can try to resolve it's IVariableBinding, and ignore the null returns. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Generally even I use the ASTView plugin to give a definitive answer to such queries :-)